# FFmpeg metadata not showing in Windows?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

If I run this command

```
ffmpeg -i Acetone.wav Acetone.mp3
```

the metadata (ID3 tags) shows in ffmpeg for the output file, but not in Windows.

```
Output #0, mp3, to 'Acetone.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TPE1            : The Crystal Method
    TIT2            : Acetone
    TALB            : Legion of Boom
    TCON            : Electronica
    ITRK            : 10
    TSSE            : Lavf54.6.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
```

> [image: bad]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FFmpeg writes ID3v2.4 headers by default.

[ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-AVOptions](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-AVOptions)

Windows only supports up to 2.3. You can override this like so

```
ffmpeg -i Acetone.wav -id3v2_version 3 Acetone.mp3
```

> [image: good]